# How to migrate base password user from Gigya to WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, migration, gigya, wso2-identity-server

Should passwords be decrypted in gigya and imported into wso2 is to encrypt new ones? The risk is to drag passwords in the clear.

Should we extract the passwords with the hash and import them as such in WSO2 IS?

Are there other methods knowing that the base to migrate from Gigya to WSO2 IS about 3 million customers?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and best option to migrate users from gigya is run time user migration to WSO2 userstore. 
For that you can do the following,

- Plug the Giya userstore as a secondary userstore in WSO2 Identity Server
- Let the PRIMARY userstore as the userstore where gigya users should migrated.
- Write a custom userstore, which will first check whether user is available in PRIMARY userstore, if there authenticate from PRIMARY userstore.
  If the user is not available in PRIMARY, authenticate user from secondary userstore and if user is successfully authenticated, create the same user in the PRIMARY userstore.

We can use this custom userstore and the secondary userstore till all the users migrated to the PRIMARY userstore of WSO2 Identity Server. Once all done we can remove the secondary userstore as well as the custom userstore.

Step three of my blog explains this : https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/user-migration-to-wso2-identity-server-is-simple-and-easy-now-da7ac7052d31

Moreover, if you need help you can post your questions in our slack channel. So our developers can help you ASAP 
https://join.slack.com/t/wso2is/shared_invite/enQtNzk0MTI1OTg5NjM1LTllODZiMTYzMmY0YzljYjdhZGExZWVkZDUxOWVjZDJkZGIzNTE1NDllYWFhM2MyOGFjMDlkYzJjODJhOWQ4YjE

Comment: Cette solution de migration engendré des coûts car il faudra maintenir les solutions pendant une période suffisance. Est ce possible d'extraire dans fichier csv les utilisateurs et leur mot de passe de gigya, puis les importer dans wso2 is ? Si cette solution est possible, comment faire pour que wso2is puisse lire les mots de passe ?

Comment: Nous avons une option pour migrer les utilisateurs à partir d'un fichier CSV. Dans WSO2 Identity Server, le mécanisme de stockage des mots de passe est différent de gigya. Nous pouvons extraire les valeurs utilisateur dans un fichier CSV et y ajouter un mot de passe par défaut et activer l'option de demande de mot de passe dans WSO2 Identity Server.
Lors du téléchargement de ce fichier CSV à l'aide de l'importation en masse des utilisateurs, la fonction Demander le mot de passe étant activée, l'utilisateur recevra un e-mail pour modifier le mot de passe.

Comment: Method 1 :  https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/user-migration-to-wso2-identity-server-is-simple-and-easy-now-da7ac7052d31

Comment: Si vous pouvez décrypter et obtenir le mot de passe simple, nous pouvons le télécharger directement avec la fonction d'importation en masse d'utilisateurs. Ensuite, il sera stocké dans WSO2 DB en tant que haché et l'utilisateur peut se connecter sans aucun problème avec le nom d'utilisateur et le mot de passe existants

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Users#ConfiguringUsers-Importingusers